Installing truetype fonts
My question was reformatted and became unreadable. Here it is again
A few weeks ago I downloaded 'basis-miktex-24.1-x64' on Windows 10.
After 'miktex set-up 5.5', pdflatex worked out-of-the-box; great.
For my work I need to install truetypefont Baskerville.
Looking back at my working miktex 4.9 on Vista system I made:
 LocalTexMF/Miktex/config    udpmap.cfg     with +baskvill
           /fonts/truetype   baskvill.ttf  'Baskerville Old Face'
                 /tfm        pbvr8t.tfm     T1 encoding
                 /map        baskvill.map   refering to baskvill.ttf
           /tex/latex        t1pbv.fd       pbvr8t is 'normal' 

My document contains:
   \usefont{T1}{pbv}{m}{n}
   \newcommand{\basefontsize}{\fontsize{11.5}{13.8}\selectfont}
   \basefontsize % Make size available throughout text

The pdflatex logs show that LocalTexMf's udpmap.cfg and t1pbv.fd are accessed
But after many size adjustments the process ends with:
   <C:\Users\EHarmse\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/dpi600\ecbx1200.pk>
   Trying to make PK font pbvr8t at 483 DPI...
   The METFAONT mode is: ljfour
   Running miktex-makemf.exe...   Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed.
   
   Running miktex-ttf2pk.exe...   Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed.
   
   !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file pbvr8t): Font pbvr8t at 483 not found
   ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

The log files just repeat the same info. It looks like the document was
formatted but could not be printed because an actual font is absent.
This setup worked perfectly in Miktex 4.9 on Vista.
Could someone please tell me what is missing here and especially
where it should be stored; the file system is a mystery to me.
BTW I tried XELatex. It made a complete mess of my documents. I'd
have to start reformatting all over again.
Thanks
Thank you for looking into this. Below two files 'testbv' and a .pdf
But, this is not rocket science; apart from:
.TTF with glyphs, .TFM with spacing
.FD with shapes, .MAP to link TTF-TFM and
udpmap.CFG to add the map
what else is needed and/or where should those be stored?
I suspect that the baskvill.ttf is out of place
\documentclass{article}

\listfiles

\usefont{T1}{pbv}{m}{n}
\selectfont

\begin{document}

\input{baskvill.map}

Which font?
A bit more text to judge the font
\newline The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog

\textsc{and this?}

\end{document}

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (MiKTeX 24.4) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.8.4)  4 AUG 2024 14:45
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./testbv.tex
(testbv.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-03-14>
(C:\Users\EHarmse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\EHarmse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count188
\c@section=\count189
\c@subsection=\count190
\c@subsubsection=\count191
\c@paragraph=\count192
\c@subparagraph=\count193
\c@figure=\count194
\c@table=\count195
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+pbv on input line 5.


(C:/DATAFILES/TEXFILES/LocalTexMF\tex/latex\t1pbv.fd
File: t1pbv.fd 2005/01/29 EBH definitions for T1/pbv.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/pbv/m/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/pbv/l/n' tried instead on input line 5.

(C:\Users\EHarmse\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-p
dftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2024-03-14 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count196
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
) (testbv.aux)
\openout1 = `testbv.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
 (baskvill.map)
Overfull \hbox (12.84793pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--11
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 pbvr8t BaskOld-Face " T1Encoding ReEn-code-Font " <T1-WGL4.en
c <baskvill.ttf
 []


Overfull \hbox (6.23682pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--11
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 pb-vrsc8t BaskOld-Face " T1Encoding ReEn-code-Font " <T1-WGL4.e
nc <baskvill.ttf
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 6--11

 []

[1

{C:/Users/EHarmse/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}]
(testbv.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-03-14>
 ***********


 *File List*
 article.cls    2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   t1pbv.fd    2005/01/29 EBH definitions for T1/pbv.
l3backend-pdftex.def    2024-03-14 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
baskvill.map
 ***********

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 482 strings out of 474423
 9168 string characters out of 5740775
 1926496 words of memory out of 5000000
 22903 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 558782 words of font info for 38 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 35i,5n,50p,129b,111s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
<C:/Users/EHarmse/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/c
m/cmcsc10.pfb><C:/Users/EHarmse/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/publi
c/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on testbv.pdf (1 page, 31091 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 16 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)

The printed .pdf looks like Computer Modern
baskvill.map
% This is EBH's additional map file for BaskerVille
%
%pbvr BaskOldFace " TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <8r.enc <baskvill.ttf
%                                                   8r misses the Dutch ij
%                                                   T1-WGL4 equals T1
pbvr8t BaskOldFace " T1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <T1-WGL4.enc <baskvill.ttf
% This stmnt tells Postscript: Use BaskOF from bask.ttf for Latex' pbvr8t
%               expect input text in T1 coding use table T1.enc to recode
% Include SmallCaps font
pbvrsc8t BaskOldFace " T1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <T1-WGL4.enc <baskvill.ttf

\ProvidesFile{t1pbv.fd}
   [2005/01/29 EBH definitions for T1/pbv.]
%   With PTM substitutions for bold and italic
\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{pbv}{}

%DecFontShape(Encode-Fam-Wght-Shape-Size
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{db}{n}{   <-> pbvr8t}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{db}{sc}{   <-> pbvrsc8t}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{db}{sl}{   <-> pbvr8t}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{db}{it}{   <-> pbvr8t}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{l}{n}{   <-> pbvr8t}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{l}{sc}{   <-> pbvrsc8t}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{l}{sl}{   <-> pbvr8t}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{l}{it}{   <-> pbvr8t}{}

%The following stmnts 'Silently Substitude' TimesRoman
%definitions for the shapes: b, bx, m-it and m-sc
%All others use one of the above definitions

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{b}{n}{<->ssub * ptm/db/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * ptm/b/n}{}
%\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{b}{sc}{<->ssub * ptm/db/sc}{}
%\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub * ptm/b/sc}{}
%\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{b}{sl}{<->ssub * ptm/db/sl}{}
%\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{bx}{sl}{<->ssub * ptm/b/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{b}{it}{<->ssub * ptm/db/it}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{bx}{it}{<->ssub * ptm/b/it}{}
%
%\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{b}{n}{<->ssub * pbv/db/n}{}
%\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * pbv/b/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{b}{sc}{<->ssub * pbv/db/sc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub * pbv/b/sc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{b}{sl}{<->ssub * pbv/db/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{bx}{sl}{<->ssub * pbv/b/sl}{}
%\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{b}{it}{<->ssub * pbv/db/it}{}
%\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{bx}{it}{<->ssub * pbv/b/it}{}
%
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{m}{n}{<->ssub * pbv/l/n}{}
%\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{m}{sc}{<->ssub * pbv/l/sc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{m}{sl}{<->ssub * pbv/l/sl}{}
%\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{m}{it}{<->ssub * pbv/l/it}{}
%
%\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{m}{n}{<->ssub * ptm/l/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{m}{sc}{<->ssub * ptm/m/sc}{}
%\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{m}{sl}{<->ssub * ptm/l/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{pbv}{m}{it}{<->ssub * ptm/m/it}{}
\endinput


I can't help with miktex but if it is trying to make pk files it has not seen the map file specifying to use the scalable font.

Test first with everything in one directory and add the map file line in a minimal hello world document. If that fails add \listfiles, post the file and complete log.

what is \input{baskvill.map} supposed to do? if you really want to use \usefont etc., do it in a local group in the body of the document. there's no point doing it in the preamble. what's the content of the map file fragment and the font definition file? are you trying to use this font for a specific element of the document, as the default serif or what?

If possible, can you post the content of the .map file?

Thank you both for looking into this
a) You asked to include the map file
b) \usefont is the way I've been getting my fonts
c) In the body I copy the .MAP and .FD
But again, those specs work on an older system.
I'm sure I just have them in the wrong place

Since you didn't mention it, I figure I'd ask: did you use MikTeX's "refresh font maps" (which should be in MikTeX Console under "Tasks")?

\input{baskvill.map} just typesets the map file. the map file looks about right (though I doubt you get small-caps this way?). the fd file looks a rather odd, but I can't see why it wouldn't work. so presumably the issue is you've not installed the map file fragment successfully. since I don't use miktex, probably best to listen to the others ;).

Thank you all for your assistance. I solved the problem by adding \pdfmapfile{=baskvill.map} to the input .TEX file. At first glance the document looks exactly equalto the original. As I'm a writer not a programmer this is good enough for me. BTW I did refresh the font maps and do get small caps.

@EBH oh, you might get fake small-caps that way. I forget about that possibility. try + rather than = for the map file.
